# Same identical response, rejected in Scrapy, accepted in Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a web site. Before writing the code, I copied the request from the browser's network tool as a curl and pasted it into Insomnia (like Postman). I could resend the same request with an 200 response in Insomnia.

However, when I mimic the same request in a scrapy Request with the same body, url and header; Scrapy receives 403 responses. On the other hand, if I populate a Python code with requests library through Insomnia; the identical request works in requests library.

So how could two identical requests sent in Scrapy and Requests have different responses, that is, the one Scrapy send fails whereas the one Requests sents succeeds?

Thank you

Comment: https://michael-shub.github.io/curl2scrapy/ - I guess this service can help you for getting the correct code.

Comment: They might deny the request based on scrapy's default user agent, unless you set a custom one.

Comment: I have User Agents

Comment: I send exactly the same request including its headers

Comment: @Serhii could you add your comment above as an answer so that I can give it a check sign? It doesn't conceptually address my situation but functionally, IT WORKED!

I could populate the Scrapy Requests which is totally identical to a working requests request. I just pasted the working request from Postman or Insomnia into that page and voilà! I got my 200 <3

Comment: @Serhii also, could tell me if you know why this tools always sets don_filter to True in every conversion?